# How do I remove negative elements from two-dimensional array which are on the main diagonal with C

Tags: c, algorithm

I have an array:

```
int a[3][3] = {  
    {-1, 2, 3} ,
    {4, -5, 6} ,
    {7, 8, -9}
};
```

I want the final result to be the same array but without the negative elements.

```
int a[3][2] = {  
    {2, 3} ,
    {4, 6} ,
    {7, 8}
 };
```

I do not know how to perform my algorithm correctly so, please help me!

Comment: What do you mean by "without"? Do you mean that you want them to be replaced with `0`? because, an array like that cannot be resized.

Comment: What should be the result if some of the elements are positive?

Comment: It is understood that all elements in the main diagonal are negative. I thick I got the right answet. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @machine_1 said in the comment there are two solutions.

First, replace negative numbers with zero

```
    n, m = 3;
    int a[n][m] = ...
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++){
            if (i == j && a[i][j] < 0)
                a[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
```

or simplified

```
    n, m = 3;
    int a[n][m] = ...
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < n && j < n; j++, i++){    
        a[i][j] = 0;
    }
```

Second solution is to remove that element. But! You can not remove it from from array like this. Solutions is to build new two matrix. Here you need to be careful of setting the right size of "newMatrix" matrix.

```
    n, m = 3;
    int a[n][m] = ...
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++){
            if (i == j && a[i][j] > 0) {
                newMatrix[k][l] = a[i][j];
                //increment k and l
                continue;
            }
            if (i != j)
                newMatrix[k][l] = [i][j];
                //increment k and l
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!